# Can you host a party at a public polling place during voting hours?

Tags: united-states

We are a group on a college campus im Ohio. we are completely nonpartisan and are looking to host a “party at the polls” on an off campus polling location where our students vote. It is at an apartment complex and we were denied permission by them. Are polling places considered public places during voting hours or is there any loop hole to get around this?

Comment: That somewhere is a public place does not necessarily mean that you are allowed to organize parties/concerts/meetings without the proper permits. And if it is a private place, you will of course need at least the permission from the owner.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons I agree, this is probably a better fit on Law. A quick google search turned up [this Ohio law](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/3501.35). Just because a place is "public" or not does not mean that the people in charge of the place can't restrict or control access.

Answer (score 6):

They are not considered public places in the way you mean, and in fact, the [Ohio revised code](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/3501.35) specifically prohibits the kind of behavior you're referencing. Bottom line, any kind of party at the polling place itself is out of the question due to the possibility of limiting access or intimidating potential voters.

Comment: Good thing too. Think about how a malicious group who wanted to *prevent* people from voting might use that.

Comment: @Tyler In the interest of encouraging voting, though, you could host a party on-campus and use the 'I Voted' stickers as admission.